# Accessing embedded ActiveMQ Artemis with JNDI

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

In production we use a commercial JMS broker that is not directly supported by Spring Boot (there is no starter project and there are no application properties for it). We access the connection factory via JNDI. In test scope, I would like to replace the broker we use in production with an embedded in-memory ActiveMQ Artemis broker, but I have trouble accessing it.

Here is our main class:

```java
@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(
      @Value("${jms.jndi-context-factory}") String jndiContextFactory,
      @Value("${jms.broker-url}") String brokerUrl) throws NamingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, jndiContextFactory);
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, brokerUrl);
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    return (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }
}
```

This is the receiver:

```java
@Component
public class Receiver {

  private final BlockingDeque<String> receivedMessages = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(100);

  @JmsListener(destination = "testtopic")
  public void receive(Message<String> message) {
    receivedMessages.add(message.getPayload());
  }

  public String getNextReceivedMessage() {
    try {
      return receivedMessages.poll(1_000L, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The main application.yml configures topics and JNDI properties:

```yaml
spring:
  jms:
    pub-sub-domain: true

jms:
  jndi-context-factory: '<COMMERCIAL_BROKER_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY>'
  broker-url: '<COMMERCIAL_BROKER_URL>'
```

Here is some test code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class ReceiverTest {

  @Autowired
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private Receiver receiver;

  @Test
  public void receive() {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("testtopic", "Hello World!");

    String message = receiver.getNextReceivedMessage();

    assertThat(message).isEqualTo("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Inside the test application.yml (src/test/resources/config), I override the JNDI information:

```yaml
jms:
  jndi-context-factory: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory'
  broker-url: 'vm://0'
```

Our Maven POM looks like this:

```xml
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commercial-broker-groupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>commercial-broker-artifactid</artifactId>
      <version>${commercial-broker-version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>artemis-jakarta-server</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>      
    </dependency>          
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
 </dependencies>
```

But it's not working. I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:510)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:664)
    at test.ReceiverTest.receive(ReceiverTest.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:867)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:279)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:703)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:865)
    ... 77 more
```

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.5 and Java 17. This used to work with Spring Boot 2 and ActiveMQ Classic. With ActiveMQ Classic I used to use the URL `vm://localhost` which I've also tried and which generates the same exception. What am I missing? Is it no longer possible to access the embedded broker via JNDI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in your configuration where you're actually starting an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis.

I believe the difference is that in ActiveMQ "Classic" an instance could be started automatically behind-the-scenes when using a `vm://` connection. This behavior isn't currently implemented by ActiveMQ Artemis so you'll need to [start an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis yourself](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html) or use something like `spring-boot-starter-artemis` as noted in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html).

If there is, in fact, an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis running it's likely not configured with an `acceptor` configured with `vm://0`. In this case I'd recommend using this in your `application.yml`:

```
jms:
  jndi-context-factory: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory'
  broker-url: 'tcp://localhost:61616'
```

Comment: I added the dependency ```artemis-jakarta-server```. That causes Spring Boot to create an embedded broker. In fact, if I remove the connection factory from the ```Main``` class and use the one Spring Boot creates, it works, so I know that one is already started. I just don't know the exact URL or in case in the URL is correct what I need to do in order to be able to access it via JNDI.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. Let me know if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, unfortunately, it's the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is. The embedded broker is simply not started when you define your own `ConnectionFactory`. That's presumably because of the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation on the `ArtemisAutoConfiguration` class:

```java
@AutoConfiguration(before = JmsAutoConfiguration.class, after = JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ ConnectionFactory.class, ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ArtemisProperties.class, JmsProperties.class })
@Import({ ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.class, ArtemisXAConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class,
        ArtemisConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class })
public class ArtemisAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: So there wasn't an embedded broker running after all?

Comment: There isn't when I create my own `ConnectionFactory`. There is if I don't.

Comment: Given that I'm not clear on why you rejected my answer. There was, in fact, no embedded broker running (despite your comment otherwise), and if you had done this with ActiveMQ "Classic" an embedded broker _would_ have been started automatically behind-the-scenes since you were using a `vm://` connection. Of course, this won't happen with ActiveMQ Artemis which is why you need to start your own.

Comment: An embedded broker is normally started automatically by Spring Boot, just not when you create your own ConnectionFactory. You did indeed gave me the correct answer though and I'm therefore going to accept it.